# How to solve the ref keyword issue in C#(WCF Contracts)?

Tags: c#, wcf, managed

I have tried to host my Wcf service with Entlib 5.0 Validation. When servie operation contracts go for validation they get crash. Whiel investigating, I found that ref keyword in Wcf service's operation giving this problem. E.g.:

Operation contract in service is like:

```
public void GetData(int ID, string name, ref string location) {};
```

Now, while validating string location, it gets crash and if I remove ref keyword it works fine.

### Though, in EntLib version 4.0 there are no such issues.

I tried replacing `ref` with `out` the issue was solved.

But "ref" replacing with "out" means [in, out] was replaced with out. it creating some initialization probleems.

```
 can you please help me out?
```

Comment: In place of ref, use IntPtr.

Comment: *"if I remove ref keyword it works fine"* - so remove it then.

Comment: hi Tom i tried that one,it won't work for me. Here we are using some managed c++ wrappers, all core functionality in native C++.we are using WCF service.

Comment: hi vikky, i am not using pinvoke functions . intptr is usefull for c++/cli wrappers , is it?

Comment: hi all, can you please help me out with this